# .Count' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'

Tags: entity-framework-core

I would like to get .count() in include query instead of getting all data and counting on the business layer. I am getting error

The expression 'd.Records.Count()' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty')

My Entity is

```
public class Customer{
          public int Id{get;set;}
          public ICollection<Record> Records{get;set;}
}
```

My query is

```
Query.Include(r=>r.Records.Count());
```

if I pull all records using below

```
Query.Include(r=>r.Records);
```

and count at the business, it works. But I don't want to do it.

Experts,
Any Suggestion???

Comment: `Include` forces eager loading, it's not a JOIN or subquery. You don't even need it if the rest of the query uses the related entities. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What's the actual query you want to execute? `.Include(r=>r.Records)` that doesn't pull anything. Right now you haven't posted *any* query.

Comment: Are you trying to count records by customer? `context.Customers.Select(c=>new {Customer=c,RecordCount=c.Records.Count()}).ToList();`. Do you want only the count by ID or name? Select the relevant fields instead of the full object `.Select(c=>{Name=c.Name,ID=c.ID,RecordCount=c.Records.Count()}).ToList();`. EF Core will generate a SQL query *only* when the time comes to generate results, ie in `ToList()`. The entire query will be converted to SQL.

Comment: I will use .ToList() to prevent eager loading

Comment: `ToList()` has nothing to do with eager loading. Whether you use `ToList()`, `ToDictionary()` or `foreach(var item in query)`, EF will eagerly load the related object if you use `Include()`, when the time comes to generate the results. `query` is just that, a query. You still haven't explained what query you want to create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to select the count instead of including it.

```cs
.Select(c => new { Id = c.Id, Count = c.Records.Count() })
```